# How do you share a variable between two kv files?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to share the text input that I get from one kv (createscreen) file to another (info).
First kv file:

```
# :import MDTextField kivymd.textfields.MDTextField
#:include homescreen.kv
#:include infoscreen.kv
#:include alrt.kv
<CreateScreen>
    MDTextField:
        name: "stock_request"
        id: stock_request
        hint_text: "Enter a valid stock"
        helper_text: "Ex: AAPL, aapl"
        helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
        mode: "rectangle"
        width: 300
        size_hint_x: None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        on_text_validate: app.gather_stock(stock_request.text)
        on_text_validate: app.change_screen("info_screen")
```

second kv file:

```
# :import MDTextField kivymd.textfields.MDTextField
#:include homescreen.kv
#:include alrt.kv
#:include createscreen.kv
<InfoScreen>
    GridLayout:
        rows:1
        pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
        size_hint: 1, .1

        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        MDLabel:
            text: "MACD"
            font_size: 50
            font_style: "H6"
            halign: "center"

        MDLabel:
            text: ""
            font_size: 50
            font_style: "H6"
            halign: "center"
```

I want to change the text of the last MDLabel to the input of the createscreen kv file.